# Employer has not responded with interview time and date

Tags: interviewing, email

Recently I received requests for interviews from two employers.  Two days ago I replied with my preferred times and dates, but I have received no response. One employer said they wanted to meet me this week. Now, it's already half way through the week and I've heard nothing.

One important detail I want to include: One employer sent the interview request on Saturday and the other sent it on Thursday of last week. I did not know they were in the inbox until Monday (I know it was foolish of me).  My career cousnselors say I should be fine, but I am getting a little concerned about the lack of response. Have I screwed up or is it still possible that I will get a response?

Comment: People who do the interviews have work to do and are probably busy.  Relax.  I would follow up with the contact asking if they have heard anything tomorrow.  But I would not press harder until you have a decision to make.

Comment: In an effort to improve understandability, I edited this to clean up the grammar.  If I've changed your meaning, please roll back the edit or make edits yourself.

Comment: You do realize the opportunities could go away without it being your fault, right?

Comment: If someone emails you on Thursday, it is not unreasonable to reply on Monday.

Comment: Anything is possible and the world is full of jobs.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of things that could have happened. They could no longer have the position avaiable due to a hiring freeze in which case they are unlikely to contact you. They could have hired someone else in which case they are unlikely to contact you. The hiring offical could have had a family emergency and probably forgot to contact you because he was more concerned about his wife in the hospital. Or they could be mad at you for repsonding late, and they would not be likely to contact you.  Notice that contacting you isn't high on their list in any of these scenarios.

I assure you that if they are still interested, they will contact you. Otherwise move on and be more careful not to let things wait the next time just in case that is why you lost the opportuntity. Never wait until you hear back from someone to pursue other opportunities.

You could follow up once and only once to see about the scheduling, but do not become a pest or you will find yourself on the do not hire list.